# Summation of finite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I look for a neat expression of the following finite series:

$\sum_{n=1}^{a} \frac{(1-x)^{n}}{n}$

with $x\in(0,1)$.

I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-x)^{n}}{n}=-ln(1-x)$, however, I have no idea how/whether to get a neat expression for the finite series.

Is there any way?

---

Add-on: for the sake of completeness, my original challenge is to find an expression for
$\int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{a-1} (1-x(y))^{n}dy=\int_0^1 \frac{1-(1-x(y))^a}{x(y)}dy$.

Since I cannot compute that integral, I used $\int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{a-1} (1-x(y))^{n}dy=\sum_{n=1}^{a} \frac{(1-x(1))^{n}}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{a} \frac{(1-x(0))^{n}}{n}$, which leads me to the question asked above.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the word "series" usually means an infinite sum, so a "finite series" would just be a sum

Comment: What is the derivative of $\sum_{n=1}^{a} \frac{y^{n}}{n}$? What if then you replace $y$ with $1-x$ after looking at the antiderivative?

Comment: That makes sense. Please see my add-on in my question above, i.e. I guess you are referring to my original challenge?

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $y=1-x$
$$\sum_{n=1}^a\frac{(1-x)^n}{n}=\int \sum_{n=1}^ay^{n-1}dy$$
$$=\int \frac{1-y^a}{1-y}dy$$
$$=\int \frac{(1-x)^a-1}{x}dx$$
$$=\int \frac{\sum_{n=1}^a {a \choose n}(-x)^n}{x}dx$$
$$=\int -\sum_{n=1}^a {a \choose n}(-x)^{n-1}dx$$
$$= -\sum_{n=1}^a {a \choose n}\frac{1}{n}(-x)^{n}+C$$
Putting $x=0$ we get $C=H_a$ the $a^{th}$ harmonic number.

As a side note, your 'finite series' is what we would usually call a polynomial. What I have done above is compute the coefficients.